# URL Rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I trying to write "rewriting rule" in .htaccess file

I have php file on my server by name go.php

This file is use to forward/redirect to provided url/link

For example: mydomian.com/go.php?url=http://www.google.com/

It works perfect but 
I want to make it like mydomain.com/?http://www.google.com/

my htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ go.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This one does not work then I tried

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ go.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^/?$ go.php?url=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` is automatically carried forwarded to new URI.

Comment: Its good you see you bro
I have tried your provided code but if gives The requested URL /go.php was not found on this server and index.php also flash

Comment: But you wrote that `mydomian.com/go.php?url=http://www.google.com/` is a working URL

Comment: Yes, currently i'm testing it on localhost and local link is http://localhost/folder/go.phpp?url=http://www.google.com/
Its working :(

Comment: I have tried it in root folder I mean in www folder and call it by localhost/?http://www.google.com but its not sending ?url= to script

in my script there is if condition

if(!isset($_GET['url']))
    die("URL not set");

now error
URL not set

Comment: Thank you so much bro. Now its works like champ. Can you share social acccount/email with me.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. I have provide my twitter handle and linked in account in my SO profile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the second one is that the question mark is a Regex special character that effectively means "if it exists."  So the second example won't work because it's saying that the URI *could* start with a slash.

This is untested, but I think it should be as simple as escaping the question mark so that it's viewed as a character. Like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/\?(.*)$ go.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Note the extra slash before the question mark which identifies it as a string and not a special character.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer but it not working :( It show index file of directory